# (C#) Go Back to Timestamp from "long recordingId = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();"

Tags: c#, java

The "recordingId" is generated in an android-app in Java. Now I´m writing a programm for Windows (C# (Windows Forms)) and need to read-out the date and time from this long.
Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1):

Your question isn't entirely clear, but it sounds like you want a `DateTime` corresponding to the "milliseconds since the unix epoch" value stored in a Java `Calendar` and `Date`. In that case:

```
private static readonly DateTime UnixEpoch = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0,
                                                          DateTimeKind.Utc);

public static DateTime FromMillisecondsSinceUnixEpoch(long milliseconds)
{
    return UnixEpoch.AddMilliseconds(milliseconds);
}
```

You might also consider using `DateTimeOffset`, or indeed my `[Noda Time][1]` library, where you'd use the existing `Instant.FromMillisecondsSinceUnixEpoch` method.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
timestamp = new Timestamp(recordingId);
```